# Get standard timefrom textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a read only textbox which is showing value like `20/05/14` format(d/m/y).

When I try to get the value in standard format from it using

```
var reDate=new Date($("#ReturnDate").val());
```

I am getting value like `Thu Aug 05 1915 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)`
which is not correct. Why does this happen?

Because I need to get difference of two dates (where one is current date) I need in this way.

Thanks for having time.

Comment: A very nice js library when you are working with dates is [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). You can format dates, calculate dates, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var reDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date($("#ReturnDate").val()))
```

Comment: 05/05/1995 this is what i get

Comment: Did you have anything else that change textbox value? This is not normal. What value you send?

Comment: What do you mean in standar time? Standard format dd/mm/yy?

Comment: like Thu Aug 05 1915 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time) when I use var me=new Date(reDate); it gives me 1995

Comment: reDate = Thu Aug 05 1915 00:00:00 GMT+0600?

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

Comment: why I need to do like this?